# Firebase automatically updating values using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm doing is exporting phone number & owner's name from iPhone address book.

Here is the code:

```
dbRef = Database.database().reference()


let nameData  = ["contactName": contact.name ]
let phoneData = ["contactPhone": contact.phone]


self.dbRef.child("user/contacts").childByAutoId().setValue(nameData)

self.dbRef.child("user/contacts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

     if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

            for child in result {

                let orderID = child.key
                self.dbRef.child("user/contacts").child(orderID).updateChildValues(phoneData)
            }
        }
     })
```

But the result is looking like that: ContactPhone's values are changing automatically, non-stop until I stop the xCode simulator.

[image]

Can Somebody help me, please.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is combine the `nameData` and `phoneData` in single dictionary and set this in contact.

```
dbRef = Database.database().reference()
let data  = ["contactName": contact.name, "contactPhone": contact.phone ]
self.dbRef.child("user/contacts").childByAutoId().setValue(data)
```

Side note: Remove this observing code and put at some other place like in `viewDidLoad`.

**Edit:** If you want to set both separately then you need to get reference of that  `childByAutoId`.

```
dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("user/contacts").childByAutoId()
let nameData  = ["contactName": contact.name ]
let phoneData = ["contactPhone": contact.phone]
self.dbRef.setValue(nameData)
self.dbRef.updateChildValues(phoneData)
```

Comment: Thank you! But Isn't it possible if i use nameData and phoneData separatly, not in single dictionary?

Comment: @KUNWOOMYUNG Then you need to reference of that `childByAutoId`

Comment: Cool, Thanks again !

Comment: @KUNWOOMYUNG Check the edited answer for that, but its not the preferred way